# Getting a specific value inside a JSON array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to get the value of a specific attribute in a JSON file but instead I get a row content of the array.

For example that's my JSON file:

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "type1" , "pred" , "type2" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "type1": { "type": "Collection" } ,
        "type2": { "type": "has" } ,
        "type3": { "type": "contributor" }
      } ,
      {
        "type1": { "type": "Collection2" } ,
        "type2": { "type": "has2" } ,
        "type3": { "type": "contributor2" }
      } 

]
}
}
```

I want to get only the values of attribute "type3" 
But my following code gets me all of them.

```
JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(json);      
JSONObject results = obj.getJSONObject("results");
JSONArray bindings = results.getJSONArray("bindings");       

for (int i=0; i<bindings.length(); i++)
{
JSONObject x = bindings.getJSONObject(i);                
x.getJSONObject("type3");  
}
```

I tried several approaches but it seems I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: why are you iterating on json, which is a single object, shouldnt you be iterating over bindings under result eg .. for (int i=0; i<bindings.length(); i++)

Comment: I tried with (int i=0; i<bindings.length(); i++)  aswell, I just changed to see the results as I was trying other stuff. Thanks for the remarque I 'll update on the question. But Still I don't know how I can get a specific value :(

Comment: I think Here, you are getting value of type3 as "{ "type": "contributor2" }" . and thats correct. what else do you want to get ?

Comment: I'm actually getting this :   "type1": { "type": "Collection" } , "type2": { "type": "has" } , "type3": { "type": "contributor" }. 
And I only want to get this : { "type": "contributor" }.

Comment: What specific value do you want? Your code clearly shows you understand when to use an array vs an object. From an object, you can do a simple `get` on a key

Comment: This code is showing me "type1": { "type": "Collection" } , "type2": { "type": "has" } , "type3": { "type": "contributor" }. I need only the last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only want to get this : { "type": "contributor" }

Then get that value (roughly) like so

```
bindings.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("type3")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use JsonPath.read to get all Type3 values as list.

List value = JsonPath.read(bindings, "..type3");